Merge nuget feeds into one feed in Azure DevOps
In our organization we have multiple external and internal nuget feeds with different credential settings. Maintaining these feeds using a Nuget.config which is under source control turned out to be a problem if the token of a feed has changed, because moving back in history doesn't work anymore, since the token in the history is not valid.
So our idea was to have still have the Nuget.config but to create a nuget feed in Azure DevOps that merges all nuget feeds into one and store/manage the credentials on the server.
It seems though that I cannot create upstream sources from external nuget servers, for example jfrog artifactory or telerik (see: Use an external (private) nuget server as upstream source in Azure Artifacts?) and the attached MS developer suggestion: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/custom-public-upstream-sources-in-nuget-package-ma/366068, but nothing has changed since the last 6 years.
Is there any new insight how this can be accomplished?

I am afraid that Azure DevOps still not supports adding external Nuget server sources as upstream sources.
Refer to this doc: Enable upstream sources in an existing feed

Custom public upstream sources are only supported with npm registries.

Currently, Azure DevOps Feed only supports add Public Source(e.g. nuget.org), feeds from current or other Azure DevOps Organizations and Custom NPM registries as Upstream Source.
If we need to use nuget source from external Nuget Servers in Azure DevOps, we need to use Nuget.config file to reference the external Nuget source

Thanks for the feedback. This is a real problem in enterprise environments. You then need to expose passwords and login credentials to every developer (which can be a huge security issue).

@msedi Yes. I can fully understand your concern.  But there is currently no clear time for Azure DevOps developers to release this feature. I suggest that you can add the comment in the suggestion ticket you shared in question to share your concern. On the other hand, I suggest that you can save the nuget.config file  in Azure DevOps secure file https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops to protect the credentials in the nuget.config.

If this feature is released in Azure DevOps in the future, I will update my answer to remind you

Alright. Thanks. However, putting the files in the secure store only and not having the nuget.config  in the repo does not help, because developers need to have access to the nuget feed since they need access to the libraries.

@msedi Yes. I understand. This method is only used to not directly expose the nuget.config file in the repo. When the pipeline needs to use it, you can use task to download it.

In the end no, I'm just waiting until this is possible in Azure DevOps ;-)

I will update to you once the feature is achieved
